# Convert vector file to raster with text information on QGIS

Tags: qgis

[image]

I would like to convert a vector file to raster with "Field to use for a burn-in value" = VAL11 and keep "LITOTIPO" = 11 as text data.
In the final raster map I would like to have VAL 11 and LITOTIPO 11.

Comment: What do you mean by "keep column as text data"?

Comment: The data element "LITOTIPO" is a text format.
So I would like the text value "LITOTIPO" to appear in the final raster map.

Comment: And where and how should it appear?

Comment: In the rasterized file I would like to have VAL as a number and LITOTIPO as text.
However, when I rasterize the vector, I lose the text data LITOTIPO.

Comment: That is because you can't store text data in raster form.